# Information of pearson residual

Tags: residuals

I have seen [Pearson residuals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45479/pearsons-residuals) but I would like to know what do I gain from the information of the residuals in the sense of its magnitude?
Let's say I have a residual in the size of 0.001 and one of the size 1. What does this mean? How can I use this information? Up to now I only know that it's better the lower the residual is. But how to decide which magnitude is reasonable to worry about?

Comment: This is not really done, since residual magnitude depends on the data. If your data comes from a distribution with small variance then your residuals will also be small, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you! So when it relates to the same data, the magnitude itself does not matter but, for example, when you compare the residuals of different models to each other?

Comment: If for ex. you were to build a linear model and a quadratic model (on the same data), then you could compare the residual magnitudes to conclude if a quadratic model better fits your data. However, as I said, this is not really done as residuals from different models (using different methodologies) are not comparable.

Comment: Mh, ok, thank you! So how can I then use the residuals? For the same model but different data?

Comment: @user2974951's comments are a little off-target. Pearson residuals are in effect standardized, so comparisons between residuals from different models, although rough, are not ruled out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pearson residuals are the raw residuals divided by the expected dispersion (standard deviation) assumed by the fitted model for the respective residual.

In other words: Pearson residuals quantify the difference between model / observed in units of the dispersion of the fitted model.

For a normal distribution, you expect roughly 68% of the residuals within +/-1 Pearson units, and 95% within +/- 2 Pearson units.

Comment: so a pearson model is not sensitive against transformations? In my case I transformed data to a logarithmic scale and check the residuals which are quite small (10^-3). But I'm not sure what this magnitude tells me.